# Advantage of PHP's explicit variable when used in closure

Tags: php, javascript, design-patterns, closures, anonymous-function

In PHP, if you want to access variable in the outer scope, you need to declare it explicitly, e.g.

```
$foo = 'bar';
func (function() use ($foo) {

    echo $foo;

});
```

But in JavaScript, they are implicit, e.g.

```
foo = 'bar';
func (function() {
    console.log(foo);
});
```

What are the advantages and disadvantage of these two type of closure?

Comment: Because JavaScript lives based on scopes and not on class extensions/interfaces and stuff. This is a biiig topic, you should consider to ask Google more about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In PHP, if you want to access variable in the outer scope, you need to
>   declare it explicitly [...] `use ($foo)`

Technically, your function is not accessing `$foo` in the outer scope. To do that,  you would need to:

```
$foo = 'bar';
$func = function() {
    global $foo;
    echo $foo;
};
```

This is not a closure. **No variables are closed in with the function.** If the value of `$foo` is changed, the next call to `func` will reflect that:

```
$func(); // bar
$foo = 'baz';
$func(); // baz
```

However, if we close in `$foo` with `func`:

```
$foo = 'bar';
$func = function() use ($foo) {
    echo $foo;
};

$func(); // bar
$foo = 'baz';
$func(); // bar
```

`func`'s `$foo` will retain it's value because it's been closed-over into the function.

To do the same in JavaScript, you simply create a function within a function and a closure will be created (giving the inner function access to the enclosing function's scope):

```
function getFunc(foo) {
    return function () {
        console.log(foo);
    };
}

foo = "bar";
func = getFunc(foo);
func(); // bar
foo = "baz";
func(); // bar
```

> What are the advantages and disadvantage of these two type of closure?

Using a "heap" type scope, as opposed to stack, so that the variable environment stays attached to the function allows first-class functions to be much more flexible as they can be passed around and recalled without worrying about creating (or passing in) a certain set of variables in order to make the function usable.

Comment: Quick query: is the only reason why the .js return on func 'bar' both times is because getFunc got called before the declared variable was assigned a different value? That the value was passed in (declared in `    func = getFunc(foo);`) and the script executed before the value changed?

Comment: but if you did `$func = function() use (&$foo)` it would work the same as in the JavaScript example. PHP simply has the option of capturing by value or reference; whereas JavaScript just has by reference.

Comment: They would have the same outward effect. The underlying mechanism is different though. One is a closure with a reference. The other is an anonymous function accessing a global variable.

Comment: If you read the PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php, "Anonymous functions, also known as closures", so either your first example is wrong or their document is wrong?

Comment: PHP is notorious for *redefining* programming concepts, e.g., [overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php). Wikipedia does a nicer job on it. Notice their *two separate* articles on [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) and [anonymous functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function).

Comment: To add to @newacct's comment: If argument foo would be an object instead of a variable the closure is broken too as the argument is passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

PHP does this because it doesn't know otherwise whether you meant to use the outer variable or not, since an unset variable acts like an empty string. This type of closure is therefore required for PHP, but not for Javascript.